# Stop propagation of hover on document on mouse move event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hover

I need to stop propagation of events, aborting the `hover`behaviour on the whole document. I´ve made a simple `Test` component that calls a `mousemove` handler in the whole document:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./Test.css";

class Test extends Component {

    state = {
        posX: 0,
        posY: 0
    }

    componentWillMount = () => {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    };

    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove, false);
    };

    handleMouseMove = event => {

        this.setState ({
            posX: event.pageX,
            posY: event.pageY
        })

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    };

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1>Pos X: {this.state.posX}</h1>
                    <h1>Pos Y: {this.state.posY}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default Test;
```

My `Test.css`:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

.content:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The example code above is running [at here](https://codesandbox.io/s/81wj81r4q8) - check the `Test.js` component.

I expected that code not to hover, as I´m calling `stopPropagation/preventDefault` on the mousemove event handler, but the hovering effect (green painting) still occurs.

How can I disable that hovering effect ? Can that be done by javascript functions ?

Comment: If it's css hover effects, override the css

Comment: I do not have in hands the elements to disable hover, so I cannot apply classes to them in ReactJs. `document.addEventListener` will apply `mousemove` to the whole document.

Comment: You cannot override css :hover pseudo class with JavaScript

Comment: What mjwatts said. There's probably a way to get to it with CSS, but we'd have to see your code to help.